# Xcode: Heap corruption detected, free list canary is damaged

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, xcode6

I have this kind of error after I run the app , sometimes i have this error, sometimes no.

AppName(2794,0x195bf72a0) malloc: *** error for object 0x170143860: Heap corruption detected, free list canary is damaged
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Can anyone help me, thank you.